# Using arithmetic in new commands

Tags: macros

Attempting to write a command that will produce a line of circles with the first `n` filled. Desired functionality would be `\IBmark{l}{m}` where `l` is the length of the line and `m` is the number of filled circles.

Using `LaTeX` in overleaf

```
\newcommand{\IBmark}[2]{\pgfmathparse{#1-#2}\textbf{\multido{}{#2}{\CIRCLE}\multido{}{\pgfmathresult}{\Circle}}}
```

Is my best attempt to get this working using the `tikz` package however it returns this

> ⚫⚫⚫.0OO

For `l = 5`, and `m = 3` rather than the desired

> ⚫⚫⚫OO

Attempts to use the rounding allowed by the `pgf print` command returned worse results. I can not seem to find a way to remove the error.

Comment: Try adding `int`, as in `\pgfmathparse{int(#1-#2)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `int(...)` to the `\pgfmathparse` calculation.

Also, in this implementation, the use of `\textbf` is irrelevant and is thus removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\CIRCLE{$\medbullet$}
\def\Circle{$\medcirc$}
\newcommand{\IBmark}[2]{\pgfmathparse{int(#1-#2)}%
  \multido{}{#2}{\CIRCLE}\multido{}{\pgfmathresult}{\Circle}}
\begin{document}
\IBmark{5}{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! From the pictures I take that you might want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\IBmark}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)},
cfill/.code={\unless\ifnum\X>#2
\tikzset{fill}
\fi}]
\path (1,-0.25ex) node (X) {\vphantom{X}}foreach \X in {1,...,#1}
{(\X*1.2em,0) node[circle,draw,minimum size=1em,cfill] {}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
Hello \IBmark{5}{3}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the vertical position of the phantom node to get any alignment you want. In principle one does not need Ti*k*Z for that but it is certainly very easy to get this done with Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 1):

If we are using OpTeX then we can do:

```
\def\ibmark#1#2{\fornum 1..#1\do{\ifnum##1>#2$\circ$\else$\bullet$\fi}}
\ibmark{5}{3}
\bye
```